# Lotus Notes SMTP 554 error

Tags: email, lotus-notes

I am a **Lotus Notes** admin, trying to fix a strange issue.

Some of the employees are getting SMTP error message while trying to execute @MailSend formula. It is strange because the same is working perfectly for the rest of the users (including me).

I created toolbar action in Lotus Notes (for different users), and wrote @MailSend formula there. Please see the error screen below:

[image]

The exactly same formula worked for most of the users, but failed for 4-5 users. Here few things to note is:

1) Destination mail system is exchange, not Lotus Domino.

2) Those users are able to send mails through outlook properly.

3) No mail file is there for any user on Lotus Domino server

4) The error message is showing 'exchange' email id of the user (i.e. test@abc.com)

Please guide me, how can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Lotus Notes clients, make sure that File, Preferences, Mail, Internet, 'Use IBM Notes as my default e-mail program' is not checked.

Also make sure current location document doesn't have any mail file/server info there.

Check local address book, names.nsf, Connections and Accounts to see if the user added any POP or SMTP accounts during installation.  Delete any that aren't part of your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info. I have checked my Lotus Notes preferences, the option 'Use IBM Notes as my default email program' is not checked there. I have mail file specified in 'Location' document (mail file location- on server, mail file- mail\xyz.nsf, domain- my server domain name). The mail send code is working fine with these settings for me, but not for other users (they also have similar configuration settings). Is there anything to do with user profile (within names.nsf)?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the message is coming from the Exchange server since the email displayed is their Exchange address. Have the Exchange Admin check to make sure they aren't part of a reject group.

Note: this should have been a comment on the OP but I don't have enough karma here yet to add comments. So please be kind.